# Parametrized decorators which share inner functions

Tags: python, decorator, python-decorators

I'm trying to make two very similar decorators, each of which accepts general `args` and `kwargs`, and both of which internally share code. The only difference between their two definitions is the value of a particular flag (which is not exposed to the user). The full context is [in this issue](https://github.com/xarray-contrib/pint-xarray/pull/143).

I currently have the first decorator defined (with no reference to the flag) as

```py
import functools


def decorator_factory(*args_units, **kwargs_units):

    def _decorator(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def _wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return f(*args, **kwargs, *args_units, **kwargs_units)

        return _wrapper
    return _decorator
```

which can be used like this

```
@decorator_factory(*args_units, **kwargs_units)
def func_to_be_decorated(*args, **kwargs):
    ...
```

What I want is to instead create two very similar decorators something like this

```py
def decorator_factory1(*args_units, **kwargs_units):
    return functools.partial(_decorator, flag=True)


def decorator_factory2(*args_units, **kwargs_units):
    return functools.partial(_decorator, flag=False)


def _decorator(func, flag):
    @functools.wraps(func)
    def _wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        if flag:
            return f1(*args, **kwargs, *args_units, **kwargs_units)
        else:
            return f2(*args, **kwargs, *args_units, **kwargs_units)

    return _wrapper
```

which could then be used like this

```
@decorator_factory1(*args_units, **kwargs_units)
def func1_to_be_decorated(*args, **kwargs):
    ...


@decorator_factory2(*args_units, **kwargs_units)
def func2_to_be_decorated(*args, **kwargs):
    ...
```

The problem is that this pattern doesn't pass down `*args_units` and `**kwargs_units`, because they are no longer available in the local namespace within the `_decorator` function.

Comment: where are defined `f`, `f1`, `f2`?

Comment: what error you are getting when you are using this way `f1(*args, **kwargs, *args_units, **kwargs_units)`?  btw you need to pass parameter in the order like `f1(*args,  *args_units, **kwargs, **kwargs_units)`

Comment: you could merge the two decorators `decorator_factory1 & 2` into a single one by *parametrize* the `flag` as an attribute for example, smt like `class Dec: def __init__(self, flag): self.flag = flag ;  def decorator_factory(self, *args_units, **kwargs_units): return functools.partial(_decorator, flag=self.flag) ` and call it as `@Dec(True).decorator_factory(...)` ... just an idea

Comment: ... and to fix the `*args, **kwargs, *args_units, **kwargs_units` problem you could make a nested `functools.partial` call where in each call you pass a different "family" of arguments.

Comment: Where/when do you expect the actual values of `**args_units` and `**kwargs_units` to come from on the `@` line ?  The decorator is executed at 'compile' time so there are no values in there unless you have these two in global variables.

Comment: `f`, `f1`, `f2` aren't defined here because they are just a shorthand for some more complex code which depends on all the arguments that `f`, `f1`, `f2` accept.

Comment: @cards that is an interesting idea to make the flag an attribute of a class... I would have to think harder about how to use `functools.partial` to solve needing access to all the arguments though.

Comment: @Alain T. the actual usage will look like this:

```
@expects("degrees celsius")
def is_freezing(temp):
    return temp < 0
```
where here "degrees celsius" would have been passed as `args
_units` and `temp` as `args.

Comment: I think that to make the decoration process dependent from globally external functions is not a good choice, in this case they are triggered by the `flag` parameter so instead of the flag parameter I suggest dictionary mapping `{True: f1, False: f2}` or more generally `[{"flag": ..., "func": ...}, {...}]`

Comment: @cards I don't understand how your dictionary idea is meaningfully any different from `if flag f1 else f2`

Comment: in order to avoid any dependency of the decorator from any external functions you could pass them as dictionary parameter

Comment: As a dictionary parameter to the `@decorator`? The reason I don't want to do that is because I want that decorator definition to be able to accept absolutely any `args` and `kwargs`

Comment: It depends on how the decorator is implemented. In case you can 1st make an instance `dec = Dec(mapping)` and  call it as a decorator (so the mapping cannot be seen directly) `@dec(*args_units, **kwargs_units).dec` where the mapping is stored as read-only getter property... don't know if it matches the "not exposed to the user" condition

Comment: in python 3.9 a more general function signature was introduced `def f(pos1, pos2, /, pos_or_kwd, *, kwd1, kwd2):` [doc](https://docs.python.org/3.9/tutorial/controlflow.html#special-parameters) but, again, it is not enough to solve the problem